# Can anybody tell me how to use AIDL or Interprocess communication in android?

Tags: android, ipc, aidl

I need information on aidl , messenger ie interprocess communication in android .

an example is preferred .

Thanks,

Comment: Be more specific. Remember that StackOverflow is a place people come to resolve specific technical issues, not to use people as a search engine proxy. GIYF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coverage of the Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL) can be found in [the Android developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). In addition to the sample code you find there, your SDK includes AIDL demonstrations in the `ApiDemos` project -- you can download sample code for an API level via the SDK Manager.